# Trouble with core-plot example folder (examples not working)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

The examples are not working for me, why?
It tells me loadDocSet.scpt => Shell Script Invocation Error.

I have build an own example in my project and it works, but I can't open the examples.

The Linking and everything else for the configuration of core plot is done well.

Googled that problem but didn't find a solution till now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to build the documentation set instead of the proper application or framework target.  In Xcode, make sure your build scheme is set to `CPTTestApp-iPhone` or whatever the example application is that you need to build, and not `Documentation`.

Based on the latest version in the Mercurial repository, the sample applications compile just fine for me when the scheme is set as I describe above.

Comment: Thx solution was that simple!